# Is there a point at which an interface design can be considered "complete?"

Tags: usability, android, iphone

A point of lessening returns where further iteration and refinement either have a net zero benefit or are actually detrimental to the user experience?

Comment: People change, technology change, therefore interfaces has to change. They are never complete!

Comment: Sure. Where that point is is not always easy to spot.

Comment: Seems like you could statistically model it somehow and actually quantify complete as a function of how new changes are received.  I've been on that kick with everything lately though.  And we're talking about something that would not be easy to quantify.  In any case, I agree there should be a point at which you are done.  But it seems others disagree.

Comment: Not so much people changing but fashion certainly does...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Art is never finished, only abandoned.** -Leonardo da Vinci

Most projects have business requirements that eventually trump further iterations of a specific interface. There may be new interfaces that have more urgent deadlines, or it might not be worth paying your salary to refine an interface only three customers use.

Outside of business projects, everything can be made better for a certain use case. What is considered a flaw by one user could be a benefit to another.

People still reinvent the wheel and build better mouse traps despite those designs being "complete" for ages.

Comment: This is kind of my take on it as well.  I'm fascinated with the ongoing iteration and refinements of the Android UI, and I wish they would stop with Android L.  It's 'good enough' and any further changes will annoy me.  Of course as others have pointed out, my distaste could be a selling point to someone else.  I'm also pretty sure they wouldn't have got this far if not for trying things that didn't work.  As a developer there are times I have to stop iterating, knowing further refinements are going to be on the wrong side of the cost/benefit curve.  I overlooked the human factor though...

Answer (score 0):

In German, we say "Der Appetit kommt beim Essen" - to @Bluewater 's list I thus add "use cases change" (i.e., often extend). A UI can at most be complete in the sense that this year's cars are complete - after next year's motor show you'll want another.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you determin complete. Is that when you have implemente all the feature request? Is it just before your application starts to suffer from feature creep?
I do agree with the other responses that state that context and expectations of the users and other stakeholders will change over time.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct your question is if there is a point where refinement of the design can't improve the user experience or even make it worse? No, always assume there is a “better”, at least if you are in a competitive business. New technologies, hypes, desires etc. constantly come and go. That is why research and testing are so important to do at every stage over and over. You will see there's always something to improve, and if there isn't (but that's hard to believe) it is time to try something new. Any progression (even failures) will be better than stagnation.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** within a fixed period of time and fixed user story

**No** in the environment of changing technology, requirements and user expectations